# Where can the Ubuntu source code be found?

Tags: ubuntu, source-code

I am trying to find where the source code for Ubuntu is located. I
looked on google and found the answer. Apparently it is in the file
`/usr/src/linux`. I have looked for this file but I cannot find it.

Where can I find the Ubuntu source code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not installed by default in Ubuntu. Read the instructions on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile to find out how to get the source.

Comment: if it not installed , how the ubuntu run ??

Comment: @zjm1126: There's a difference b/w source code and the compiled binary file that runs. Why do you want the source code?

Comment: You run many pieces of software without having the source code on your computer, phone, car, ... Why should Ubuntu be any different?

Comment: @Asad Jibran Ahmed  i want to learn the source code .